# Missing file install.run when install PunkScan

Tags: git, bitbucket, ubuntu-14.04

I am installing PunkScan on Ubuntu 14.04, follow this guide: https://hyperiongray.atlassian.net/wiki/display/PUB/PunkSCAN+1.2.x+Deployment+Guide

In step install PunkScan, it said:

> (1) in the root directory of the project you'll find a file named install.run, run it:

`./install.run`

I have downloaded from bitbucket:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/punkspider/punkscan.git
```

I try find install.run with command: `find punkscan -name install.run`
and the result is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide is a year old, it states about PunkSCAN version 1.2.x

You can get it compressed straight from bitbucket [link here](https://bitbucket.org/punkspider/punkscan/get/v1.2.2.tar.bz2)

Or you can do this in your local repository

```
$ git tag -l                # this will list tags
$ git checkout tags/v1.2.2  # this will put you on commit tagged v1.2.2
```

Your git repository will be in *detached HEAD state* but you will get all the files you need.

**P.S.** I suggest the second way. You may use tags in future :)